# Chrome JS debugging help... where was function called?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I'm using `console.log(var_name);` to debug JS code in chrome and am wondering, is there a way to output to the console the line at which the current function was called?

Comment: I've just solved my bug everyone... thanks to all who replied!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the stack trace with the following:

```
(new Error).stack;
```

You could then use a regular expression to filter out the line number: http://jsfiddle.net/8wA74/.

```
var stack = (new Error).stack.split("\n"),
    line = /:(\d+):/.exec(stack[1]); // 1 is stack depth, format is "url:line:char"

console.log("Current function was called on line " + line[1]);
// this 1 is the number of the group in regexp
```

Comment: thanks @pimvdb, this is helpful to an extent although it's actually giving me the line where (new Error) is, not the line where the function that encompasses that was called.

Comment: @Jimmy_Bob: Then you can try changing `stack[1]` to `stack[2]`, which is one level deeper in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Not that i know of, but wouldnt it be possible to set a breakpoint instead? That surely has a stacktrace visible.

Just try to click the linenumber in the dev. console, it'll show a blue arrow and next time it hits it'll show you the stacktrace.

Comment: thanks for this, I'm sure breakpoints will be easier than console logging when I get the hang of them